# Python Discord bot doesn't go online when code is ran

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm using PyCharm to make a discord bot and I'm following a tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nW8c7vT6Hl4 ). I followed every step and at the end everything is right but whenever I run the code at the end of the video the bot doesn't go online as shown.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready.")

client.run('token')
```

obviously the 'token' is my token from the discord website but I still get issues with it.

I also don't get any errors, the code runs just fine.

This is the only thing that's shown in the "Run" window in PyCharm.

```
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\discord\venv\Scripts\python.exe
```

Comment: No other windows appear, nothing? Is there any kind of logging verbosity setting you could tweak, whether that’s in Pycharm or the library?

Comment: Right click the script and click "Run"

Comment: Try starting the script from a terminal window.

Comment: well, you could try running the code in IDLE.

Answer (score -1):

From your code, it looks like you didn't import `asyncio`.

Asyncio handles asynchronous functions and is a requirements for the discord.py library to function. To import it, type `import asyncio`. Hopefully that fixes your problem!

Comment: Asyncio wouldn't be needed as discord imports it for it's own use. If discord was imported properly, then asyncio was as well. There weren't any errors so asyncio wasn't the problem.

Comment: I always import asyncio just in case, I have some issues when it comes to not importing asyncio anyway